# Only Show an Advanced Custom Fields custom field on a specific template

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am building a site that will rely on Advanced Custom Fields to control the information displayed on a page template. Is there a way I can programmatically show a field (or fieldgroup) only when that template is selected?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out. It is a setting that can be configured from within the edit field group section of the plugin.